# Computer very slow, not connecting to network

Tags: windows-vista

My computer runs Windows Vista. It's currently extremely slow to boot and respond to user input (after boot). It's also unable to connect to the network (the surrounding SSIDs are visible but if I try to connect the computer says only limited connectivity is available). I scanned the system with AVG and another virus scanner with no results. AVG Tuner improved speed a little, but not much. System restore didn't help.

I'm thinking the best way to proceed is probably to reinstall Windows. But I don't have the Windows CD. Is it possible to do this somehow with my current system?

Answer (score 0):

Limited connectivity issues with Vista can often be improved by updating the network device drivers.

Create a Restore Point then go to the Device Manager under Administrative Tools.  RIght-click on the Network devices, both the physical card driver and the WiFi driver in turn, select Update Driver.  Yes, it will go to the net and your connectivity issues will get in the way!

Alternatively, many PCs will have a recovery partition on the HDD for reinstalling the OS without a CD/DVD.  Boot to the BIOS and look for a recovery option.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't help.